# Why C# does not allow abstract methods in non abstract class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a base class that has a "mock" method used in the same way by all the inherited classes

```
protected class User{
   protected void PrepareUser()
   {
      // init
   }

   protected abstract Display();
}

public class Person: User{
   // override display
}
```

My problem is that of course I can't declare abstract methods in a non abstract class so what would be the correct OOP approach to have a base class with an Init method triggered always in the same way and force the inherited classes to re-implement a Display method?

Comment: You can have an abstract class with method implementations, so you could make your base abstract but provide implementations for the non-abstract methods.

Comment: That's strange, I always thought this was possible. Not a solution, but a workaround would be to have your base method (not abstract) throw an Exception in its base implementation. It'd at least remind the developer he forgot to override it.

Comment: @Charleh: Making your base abstract might lead to other issues though. I assume OP wants to be able to use his `User` class directly.

Comment: Yes, true - but you could get round that by providing a base abstract underneath the `User` layer and making `User` concrete - just depends on requirement I suppose

Comment: @Charleh: putting it into `AbstractBaseUser` would mean he has to implement it in the `User` class. That doesn't solve the original issue where OP wants to force `Person` to implement its own version of a Display() method, as `Person` could just use the implementation set in `User`. That is, in effect, not different from not using an abstract class in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can have an abstract class with method implementation like bellow:

```
    protected abstract class User
    {
        protected void PrepareUser()
        {
            // init
        }

        protected abstract void  Display();
    }
```

Secondly you cannot have `protected class` if it is not inside other class. Moreover base class cannot be less accessible than subclass. SO full working code should be like:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class XXX
    {
        protected abstract class User
        {
            protected void PrepareUser()
            {
                // init
            }

            protected abstract void  Display();
        }

        protected class Person : User
        {
            protected override void Display()
            {
                //something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good catch about the use of the `protected` modifier. Totally missed that.

Comment: Yes me too, totally miss the protected modifier, that's why was not compiling :-D

Comment: @Flater most people miss it :)

Comment: @Garath: I rarely use `protected`. Mainly because most of my projects don't really require inheritance. I just never considered that it is indeed only meaningful if inside something that can partake in inheritance (i.e. a class).

Answer (score 0):

> ...so what would be the correct OOP approach to have a base class with an Init method triggered always in the same way and force the inherited classes to re-implement a Display method?

An abstract class *is* the correct approach for that. E.g.:

```
protected abstract class User{
    protected void PrepareUser()
    {
      // init
    }

    protected abstract void Display();
}

public class Person: User{
    protected override void Display()
    {
        // ...implementation...
    }
}
```

Side note: You'll also need to make `User` `public` if `Person` is going to be `public`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class User 
{
    protected void PrepareUser()
    {
       // init
    }

    protected abstract void Display();
}

public class Person : User
{
   // override display
    protected override void Display()
    {
       // Do Stuff
    }
}
```

Does the above not fit what you want?

Comment: There are some situations where it may be helpful to have an instantiable base class but still require that derived classes must override a particular method.  For example, a class which defines its own means of serializing to a compact byte stream might require that derived classes override its `WriteToByteStream` method, since the base-class method would generate a byte stream that would generate a base-class instance.